# Append to list or create new list

Tags: python

I want to add an element to a list, but the list might not exist yet. In which case, I'd create a list of that single element. It might be an entry in a dictionary. It's my responsibility to add to a particular field - hence the append. But, if it's the first time I'm doing it, the key doesn't even exist in the dictionary yet. Hence the set to a list of a single element.

So in a nutshell, the following

```
if 'dependencies' in userdata:
    userdata['dependencies'].append('foo')
else:
    userdata['dependencies'] = ['foo']
```

This feels very unpythonic and ugly. What are some better options?

Comment: What would ever be a meaningful real-world scenario where `X` is not defined at runtime, sometimes?

Comment: I mean that Python usually can be written in a fairly compact manner, while this feels very verbose.

Comment: How do you `append` to a dictionary. Dictionary objects do not have `.append`  method

Comment: I'm adding to a field in a dictionary. The field is a list.

Comment: With a dictionary, it works well to use `mydict.setdefault(key, []).append('foo')`.

Comment: thanks @MatthiasFripp. your answer made the most sense

Comment: I edit my answer. now you can work with `dict`

Answer (score 2):

use `try...except` like below:

```
try:
    X.append('foo')
except NameError:
    print("you need create list first. I create list for you. then append.")
    X = ['foo']
```

**EDIT :** base on your editing question:

```
from collections import defaultdict
userdata = defaultdict(list)
userdata['dependencies'].append('foo')
```

Comment: If this is was in a for loop, a more pythonic way would be list comprehensions, wouldn't it.

Comment: @PCM you can edit my answer for improve this

Comment: @Chris thanks a lot for your comment. is this your intention? I'm here for learning from you. can you give me example

Comment: Indeed that was my point. `X.append` still fails if `X` is `dict`, and thus raise `AttributeError`. `except` will catch that too, and blindly change a `dict` into `list`. It can even catch `KeyboardInterrupt` and modify `X`, when all user wanted to do was cancel ;)

Comment: @Chris Wow. thanks a lot. TIL(Today I Learn) from you